# ssh2_exec() wont change directory with "cd"

Tags: php, centos, plesk

I have a problem with `ssh_exec()` refusing to execute the "cd" command.

If I log into the server directly and execute the command, it works fine, so I don't think the problem is with my command.

My code is as follows:

```
$str = ssh2_exec($sshStream, 'cp /var/www/compressed.tar.gz /var/www/vhosts/demo-domain1.com/httpdocs/');
$errstr = ssh2_fetch_stream($str, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
stream_set_blocking($str, true);
stream_set_blocking($errstr, true);
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($str);
echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errstr);

$str = ssh2_exec($sshStream, 'cd /var/www/vhosts/demo-domain1.com/httpdocs/');
$errstr = ssh2_fetch_stream($str, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
stream_set_blocking($str, true);
stream_set_blocking($errstr, true);
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($str);
echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errstr);

$str = ssh2_exec($sshStream, 'tar xzf c-class.tar.gz');
$errstr = ssh2_fetch_stream($str, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
stream_set_blocking($str, true);
stream_set_blocking($errstr, true);
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($str);
echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errstr);
```

I am logged in as root.

The first command runs correctly and copies the file to the location. The second command doesn't execute, but outputs no errors. The third command displays an error (obviously as the previous cd command doesn't work).

I know it hasn't changed dirs, as when I execute the "pwd", it returns saying it is in the root dir still.

As mentioned before, if I run the commands from shell, they execute fine, so I'm 99.9% sure my syntax is correct.

This is a dedicated server provided by 1&1, running CentOS and Plesk 9.

Comment: What happens when you change the command to `cd /var/www/vhosts/demo-domain1.com/httpdocs/ || echo "cd failed"`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To execute `ssh2_exec()` PHP starts a process that will perform a `ssh` executed on the remote server.

The shell process created remotely has its own environment, including the current working directory.
The `cd` command will change the working directory of the `shell` that was started by your second command.

When that second command ends, the shell dies with it. Along with the working dir information.

In other terms, the shell environment of the command *N*  will not be remembered during the execution of command *N+1*.

If you want the shell commands to be working while depending on each other in terms of environment, you should put several commands in a unique `ssh2_exec` like

```
 $str = ssh2_exec($sshStream, 'cd /var/www/vhosts/demo-domain1.com/httpdocs/;'
                            . 'tar xzf c-class.tar.gz');

 $errstr = ssh2_fetch_stream($str, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
 stream_set_blocking($str, true);
 stream_set_blocking($errstr, true);
 echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($str);
 echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errstr);
```

Comment: Other answers on the web were very confusing, this one made it clear why its not working.  I had to put all my commands in one ssh2_exec instead of many since they followed from each other.