# Change Directory "cd" with libssh2 on iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, cd, libssh2

I want to implement something like Mac's Terminal app, but for iOS. I set up libssh2, everything is working.

I run "**cd Test**" command, where Test is a folder in working directory. Then if I run: "**pwd**", it will show me that cd command didn't change directory.

However, if I run: "**cd Test; pwd**", it will show that it changed directory.

I understand why is this happening, best explained here: 
[ssh2_exec() wont change directory :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627779/ssh2-exec-wont-change-directory)

**My question**: What's the solution for this? I want to be able to run this like in Terminal, like in a big shell, that won't die after each command. Is this possible? It's killing the user every time to change directory, then do what you want. Why if directory changed once, won't remain changed until a new cd occurs? How can I do this?

Thanks all.

**EDIT:**

Here's my method:

```
- (NSString*) execCommand: (char *)commandline { 

// Clean data;
[self.data setLength:0];

NSString *result;

int rc = 0;
int bytecount = 0;

/* Exec non-blocking on the remove host */
while( (channel = libssh2_channel_open_session(session)) == NULL && libssh2_session_last_error(session,NULL,NULL,0) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
{
    waitsocket(sock, session);
}

if( channel == NULL )
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
    return @"Error";
}

while( (rc = libssh2_channel_exec(channel, commandline)) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
{
    waitsocket(sock, session);
}

if( rc != 0 )
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
    return @"Error";
}

for( ;; )
{
    /* loop until we block */
    int rc1;
    do
    {
        char buffer[0x4000];
        rc1 = libssh2_channel_read( channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
        if( rc1 > 0 )
        {
            NSData * tmpData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:rc1];
            [self.data appendData:tmpData];

            int i;
            bytecount += rc1;
            fprintf(stderr, "We read:\n");
            for( i=0; i < rc1; ++i )
                fputc( buffer[i], stderr);
            fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "libssh2_channel_read returned %d\n", rc1);
        }
    }
    while( rc1 > 0 );

    /* this is due to blocking that would occur otherwise so we loop on
     this condition */
    if( rc1 == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
    {
        waitsocket(sock, session);
    }
    else
        break;
}

int exitcode = 127;
while( (rc = libssh2_channel_close(channel)) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
    waitsocket(sock, session);

if( rc == 0 )
{
    exitcode = libssh2_channel_get_exit_status( channel );
}
printf("\nEXIT: %d bytecount: %d\n", exitcode, bytecount);

libssh2_channel_free(channel);
channel = NULL;

result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self.data setLength:0];

return [result autorelease];}
```

Comment: Are you using `executeCommand:`? it looks like that will execute a new shell each time on the remote host and that's why `cd` wont work as you expect. I think you need to dig deeper into libssh2 to get the functionality your looking for. You need to start a shell and keep if running somehow.

Comment: I found that I have to change the channel after each command. Tried to use it for more commands, but not working. I don't see any other option from libssh2 docs and examples. Maybe somebody did this, and can share his wisdom ;)

Answer (score 0):

probably the only solution for this is to emulate the change of directory - by this I mean  changing the path stored internally which indicates where in the directory tree you currently are and using that while performing any other requests to the server. Hope this helps!